# Scrolling with javascript and 'position: sticky' div

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, sticky

I have a react app that basically is a container with 2 columns. The left column is a list and the right column is a div with position sticky(It's actually a map with pins. Must be fixed on the screen). Each list item is a clickable in the right column. When the user clicks on the title, the screen must be scrolled to display the current list item on left column.

[image: right column is fixed]

The problem is that when the screen scrolls to an item at the end of the list, the right column also scrolls and doesn't stay fixed.

[image]

I would like to keep the right column always fixed when the user clicks on some title, regardless of the element's position in the left column list.
Any idea how to fix it?

[image]

https://codesandbox.io/s/scrolling-with-react-yq81r

Answer (score 0):

I change a couple of code on CodeSandbox.

```
.right {
  background-color: #cacaca;
}

.right ul {
  top: 0;
  position: sticky;
}
```

If I understood correctly this gonna work.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't find your changes.

Comment: Delete .right style code from css file then add the code above.

Comment: Okay, but it doesn't work in my context because I need to keep the entire right column visible. The ul with the links is just to exemplify how it works.